# How to seperate query results to var Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a query result in array `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [model] => Peugeot 308 SW ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [model] => Citroen C-Elysee ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [model] => Nissan Evalia ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [model] => Renault Trafic 9-os ) )`

And I want to make a single variable for every object like:

$Peugeot 308 SW
$Citroen C-Elysee
$Nissan Evalia

But I don't know how to do that. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a single variable? An array like $cars[] or multiple variables like $car1, $car2, etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest you to use the array itself instead of saving in different single-variables.

But if you still wanna do that, the number of variables must be limited and can be defined by:

```
// Assuming the response array is $cars
$car0 = $cars[0]; //Peugeot 308 SW
$car1 = $cars[1]; //Citroen C-Elysee
$car2 = $cars[2]; //Nissan Evalia
$car3 = $cars[3]; //Renault Trafic 9-os
```

I hope that's what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You have `array of objects`.Just try like this..

```
$car0 = $array[0]->model; //outputs Peugeot 308 SW
$car1 = $array[1]->model; //outputs Citroen C-Elysee
$car2 = $array[2]->model; //outputs Nissan Evalia
$car3 = $array[3]->model; //outputs Renault Trafic 9-os
```